# Symlink folders delete themselves

Tags: linux, ubuntu, symlink

I have two **symlinks** pointing to two folders inside `var/www` on my server, and for some strange reason, those two folders **get deleted**.
Checking the `server command history`, there is no record of any command removing those folders.

Symbolic links are used for **image files** on a web page, could someone remove the folders via the web page? and how?

The strange thing is that it only happens with the folders that are related to a symbolic link.
I have researched about this problem, but have not found anything related.

Hope someone can help me.

Comment: Edit question to clarify `var/www` or `/var/www`, and is it directories or symlinks that are being deleted?

Comment: Tell us where the symlinks are, where are the folders, what are the symlinks, what is disappearing.